# Update automaticaly switch button on checked

Tags: laravel, checkbox, switch-statement, return-value

I have issues in my project.
In deed, I want to update automatically a switch button when I check it.
The case that I have is that when I click on the switch button, the page is refresh but the value is not changed.

my code :

```
<div class="col-4 text-left">
     <form  id="form" class="was-validated" method="POST" action="{{ route("admin.patients.update", [$patient->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     @method('PUT')
     @csrf
         <div style="float: right">
              <label class="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" onchange="$('#form').submit();" name="cas_suivi" id="cas_suivi" type="checkbox" {{  ($patient->cas_suivi == "cas_suivi" ? ' checked' : '') }} >
                      <div class="slider"></div>
              </label>
          </div>
       </form>
     </div>
```

the controller:

```
public function update(UpdatePatientRequest $request, Patient $patient) { $patient->update($request->all()); return view( 'admin.patients.show', (compact('patient'))->with('success', 'Le patient a bien été modifié'); }
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code

Comment: public function update(UpdatePatientRequest $request, Patient $patient)
    {
        $patient->update($request->all());

        return view( 'admin.patients.show', (compact('patient'))->with('success', 'Le patient a bien été modifié');
    }

Comment: Please post the code in question so that its easy to read

Comment: It's done  ManojKiran!

Comment: Can you post the result when you ```dd($request->all());``` inside ```update``` method

Comment: array:3 [▼
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "_token" => "Vo93U0F1uO1Ji7r03uVuENgq8JylZsEV5u6zQfRV"
  "cas_suivi" => "on"
]

Comment: Do you have ```$fillable``` property in ```Patient``` . If so post the fillable in question

Comment: Yes i Have it. So what must I do?

Comment: Do you have ```cas_suivi``` inside  ```$fillable``` property

Comment: And what are all the possible values that can be stored in that column

Comment: Yes cas_suivi is inside $fillable and the 2 values that can be stored are: on and off.

Answer (score 0):

The result is:

```
    array:3 [▼
    "_method" => "PUT"
    "_token" => "Vo93U0F1uO1Ji7r03uVuENgq8JylZsEV5u6zQfRV"
    "cas_suivi" => "on"
    ]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After updating the table you need to redirect to the page again.

**//change the route name if necessary**

```
public function update(UpdatePatientRequest $request, Patient $patient) 
    { 
        $patient->update($request->all()); 
        return redirect()
        ->route('admin.patients.index')
        ->with('success', 'Le patient a bien été modifié'); 
    }
```

Comment: Yet it's the case. It's redirecting to the same page

Comment: Is value updating

Comment: Sorry for being so lat to respond. Value is not updating